# Installing Windows on external hard drive

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive, firewire, thunderbolt

For the last half of the year, I have been using Windows installed on my external HDD, which uses USB 3.0 port, I had to install Windows (Windows 10) by copying virtual disk file into the drive. However Windows by default does not allow you to install itself on USB or IEEE 1394 port, that way now I cannot install updates for Windows 10, and some Microsoft software. My question is does Windows allow to install itself on any external drive using some other ports (Thunderbolt, FireWire, eSATA...)? I'm thinking about buying some replacement external hard drive.

[Windows installer error - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRsMZ.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to install Windows OS onto an external hard drive. The operating system is tied to the motherboard, it means that you won't be able to boot from the external HDD. Your only option to do that would be to create a Windows 8 To Go USB drive. Here's a [similar thread from SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/431906/windows-8-on-external-drive-how-to-make-a-volume-bootable). Best of luck!

Comment: Windows To Go can also be used with Windows 10. http://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/

Comment: I am sure you can do this without using Windows-to-go. I had windows 8.1 installed to a flash drive that I would boot from on every computer I used. All you would have to do is during install, have the flash drive seen as if it was an internal drive. I could provide instructions after work today.

Comment: @GabrielFair OK, I think that could do. I would appreciate all your effort if you could provide me instructions for making external drive seen as internal.